# Testing a Jest method that has multiple promises

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am attempting to write a test for a service in my app.

```
async post(url, params, headers) {
        const csrfToken = await this.getCsrfToken().then(res => res.data);
        headers.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = csrfToken;
        // console.log(params);
        return this.http.post(url, params, headers);
    }
```

The issue I am encountering is I am getting an error that data is not defined. I believe this refers to the csrfToken call (which is just another API call to get this token to append to the header).

I'm not entirely sure how to mock that constant inside jest so I can actually get to my post call. Is there an easy way in jest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to mock the constant, you should mock the getCsrfToken instead. Try something like:

```
import { getCsrfToken, post } from MyClass

it('should work', () => {
    // mock method on your class
    myMock = jest.fn()
    myMock.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve({
       data: {
         fakeCsrf
       }
    })
    MyClass.csrfToken = myMock
    post('/test', {}, {})
    expect(...);
});
```

Comment: Yep, something roughly on these lines worked. I didn't realize I should overwrite my own class methods while testing other methods.